# Vulkan issue on AMD 5700G CPU onboard Radeon....'amdgpu'?

Tags: debian, amd, vulkan

I have an AMD Ryzen 5700G and I tried installing Wine, however when I launch it I get "0074:err:vulkan:wine_vk_init Failed to load vulkan library".

I'm running Debian 10 with an updated kernel, which so far has been fine.

Then when it loads and I try to run project64 it that programme won't run, so I think there's something wrong with vulkan. I've tried installing everything and modifying grub from what I've read online, but when I run vulkaninfo I still get the following:

```
==========
VULKANINFO
==========

Vulkan Instance Version: 1.1.97

amdgpu: Invalid PCI ID.
amdgpu: Invalid PCI ID.
/build/vulkan-tools-6bmpQy/vulkan-tools-1.1.97+dfsg1/vulkaninfo/vulkaninfo.c:3845: failed with VK_ERROR_INITIALIZATION_FAILED
```

What testing can I do to further narrow down the issue, to rectify it?

Thanks very much!!

Comment: I wouldn't use Debian 10 as a desktop OS considering how fresh your hardware is. Please try something more mainstream, e.g. Fedora 37 or Ubuntu. Or at the very least the very last Debian release.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov Thanks for the reply. Ah that was not what I wanted to hear, because there are certain packages of software which I don't want to upgrade if I change Debian releases.

Comment: That's Linux in essence for you. I hope that's not something new.